# how to expand groups in sql

Tags: sql, expand, group

How can I go from:

```
organisation | individual | month      | number_consultations | mode         | professional | setting
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 7                    | face-to-face | nurse        | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 3                    | telephone    | doctor       | group1
```

To:

```
organisation | individual | month      | number_consultations | mode          | professional    | setting
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 7                    | face-to-face  | nurse           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | nurse           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | nurse           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | nurse           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | doctor          | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 3                    | telephone     | doctor          | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | doctor          | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | doctor          | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | otherdirectcare | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | otherdirectcare | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | otherdirectcare | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | otherdirectcare | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | other           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | other           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | other           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | other           | group1
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | nurse           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | nurse           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | nurse           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | nurse           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | doctor          | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | doctor          | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | doctor          | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | doctor          | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | otherdirectcare | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | otherdirectcare | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | otherdirectcare | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | otherdirectcare | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | face-to-face  | other           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | telephone     | other           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | homevisit     | other           | group2
A            | A01        | 2016-01-01 | 0                    | digital       | other           | group2
```

.....

For each organisation, individual and month, I would like to expand:

- mode (face-to-face, telephone, homevisit, digital)
- professional (nurse, doctor, otherdirectcare, other)
- setting (group1, group2, group3, group4)

How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use several `cross join`s:

```
with modes(mode) as (
   select 'face-to-face'
   union all
   select 'telephone'
   union all
   select 'homevisit'
   union all
   select 'digital'
),
professionals(p) as (
   select 'nurse'
   union all
   select 'doctor'
   union all
   select 'otherdirectcare'
   union all
   select 'other'
),
settings(s) as (
   select 'group1'
   union all
   select 'group2'
   union all
   select 'group3'
   union all
   select 'group4'
)
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.number_consultations, 0) 
from (select t.organization, t.individual, t.month, m.mode, p.p, s.s 
      from tbl t cross join modes m cross join professionals p cross join settings s) t1 
left join tbl t2 on t1.mode = t2.mode and t1.p = t2.professional and t1.s = t2.setting
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d979eaaf18bc2a20133c3faf55d75c8).

Comment: Many thanks @Ajax1234, I cannot open fiddle it says "safari cannot open the page". What does it mean modes(mode), professionals(p), settings(s)? I am having difficulties translating these to my dataset